# speed up R code - vectorize?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, vectorization, doparallel

I am struggling to make my code faster. Currently I am getting somewhere using doParallel, but I am wondering if it could be made faster though clever programming instead of faster hardware. Here is a stylized version of what I want to do:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(doParallel)
    library(data.table)
    cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(all.tests=FALSE,logical=TRUE))
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    set.seed(12345)
    crit <- 0.5
    dta <- data.frame(treat = sample(1:12,1000, replace=TRUE),
                      dep   = sample(100:200,1000, replace=TRUE),
                      uniqID = rep(1:100,length.out = 1000))
    nr_repl <- 1000

    oper <- foreach (repl = 1:nr_repl, .combine=cbind,.packages = c("data.table")) %dopar% {
        dta_sim <- data.table(dta)
        setDT(dta_sim)[,perm:=sample(treat),by = (uniqID)]
        dta_sim$recipient <- "single"
        dta_sim$recipient[dta_sim$perm == 5  |dta_sim$perm == 6  |dta_sim$perm == 7 |dta_sim$perm == 12  ] <- "couple"
        return(abs(summary(lm(dep~recipient=='couple', data=dta_sim))$coefficients[2,1]) > abs(crit) )
        }

    mean(oper)
```

After the helpful comments and suggestions, this is what I ended up with:

```
library(dplyr)
library(doParallel)
library(data.table)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(all.tests=FALSE,logical=TRUE))
registerDoParallel(cl)
set.seed(12345)
crit <- .5
dta <- data.frame(treat = sample(1:12,1000, replace=TRUE),
                      dep   = sample(100:200,1000, replace=TRUE),
                      uniqID = rep(1:100,length.out = 1000))
nr_repl <- 1000    
oper <- foreach (repl = 1:nr_repl, .combine=cbind,.packages = c("data.table")) %dopar% {
        dta_sim <- data.table(dta)
        setDT(dta_sim)[,perm:=sample(treat),by = (uniqID)]
        dta_sim$recipient <- ifelse(dta_sim$perm %in% c(5,6,7,12), "couple", "single")
            return(abs(coef(lm(dep~recipient=='couple', data=dta_sim))[2]) > abs(crit) )
        }

mean(oper)
```

Comment: The three lines `dta_sim$perm  <- c(sapply(names(... )) ... dta_sim$recipient[...] <- "couple"` look like a bottleneck, please explain in words what the code does? if you only care about sampling "couple"s, why did you bother to include the "single"s in the data you pass `lm`, why not preexclude it from being sampled? And you can replace the compound `dta_sim$perm == 5  | ...` with `dta_sim$perm %in% c(5,6,7,12)`, or even `dta_sim$recipient <- if(dta_sim$perm %in% c(5,6,7,12)) "couple" else "single"`, which is vectorized

Comment: `lm` and its `summary` method are both slow. First, just to extract a coefficient, you can use the `coef` function. Then, you don't need to use `lm` if you are able to construct a design matrix. I'd use `lm.fit` instead.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you are just computing the difference in means between the `couple` and `not couple` groups with your linear model. You don't need regression for that at all.

Comment: The example provided comes from a more general function that is tailored to a factorial experiment (with two factors, each with three levels and a pure control). In fact, the treatment levels for recipient are not (couple, single), but (couple, single man, single woman). The second factor is the person who gives the treatment, which can also be a couple, single man, or single woman. The 5, 6, 7 and 12 are thus the treatment cells in the design where the recipient == couple. But you have a point: if I am only comparing eg couples to singles, I can probably simplify the sampling.

Comment: `ind <- dta_sim$perm %in% c(5, 6, 7, 12);
  return(abs(mean(dta_sim[ind, "dep"]) - mean(dta_sim[!ind, "dep"])) > abs(crit) )`

Comment: Your time-consuming step is the permutation step. However, I'm not sure your code works as intended. If you want to permute per `uniqueID` it doesn't unless you first sort by `uniqueID`. I would use package data.table and its `by` for this step or even look for a package that implements efficient groupwise permutation..

Comment: You are right, the code does not do what I intended. Thanks so much for pointing this out. I have followed your suggestion and used data.table as you can see in the edited post. This also resulted in a substantial speed improvement. Thanks so much!

Comment: OK, I have included most of the suggestions and this made the code much faster! I have edited the original post to add the modified code.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to optimize would be to replace `names(table(dta$uniqID))` in the `sapply` call with `as.character(unique(dta$uniqID))`. Depending on your data size, this will be multiple times faster.

Benchmark with a vector of length 1,000,000:

```
x <- rep(1:100, 10000)

> test <- microbenchmark(names(table(x)), as.character(unique(x)), times = 100, unit = "s")
> test
Unit: seconds
                    expr        min          lq       mean      median          uq       max neval cld
         names(table(x)) 0.22017963 0.222114845 0.27556537 0.226181405 0.328574578 0.4403513   100   b
 as.character(unique(x)) 0.00714553 0.007643307 0.02098216 0.008296107 0.009429619 0.1173899   100  a
```

Comparing the median values, `as.character(unique(x))` performs 28 times faster than `names(table(x))`. The rest of your code seems pretty streamlined to me.